# Object Property Comparison, best way to handle null checks?

Tags: c#

I am looking through the FieldInfo of types, and collecting property information about the types. This code looks like this:

```
foreach (FieldInfo f in fi)
{
    Foo<T> v = new Foo<T>();
    v.Prop = f.Name;
    v.ValA = f.GetValue(val1);
    v.ValB = f.GetValue(val2);

    if (!v.ValA.Equals(v.ValB))
    {
        variances.Add(v);
    }
}
```

However, this code failed on the if condition, if v.ValA and v.ValB are null. I am looking for differences between objects with this, and if v.ValA is null and V.ValB are both null, it should fail the if condition. What would be the advised means on handling this?

Comment: Erm, add a null check for both values in the condition?

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as this:

```
if (v.ValA == null || !v.ValA.Equals(v.ValB))
{
    variances.Add(v);
}
```

I say that because if `v.ValA` isn't `null` but `v.ValB` is it will evaluate to `false` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
if ( !(v.ValA==null && v.valB==null) || !v.ValA.Equals(v.ValB))
```

If I read your question correctly

Answer (score 0):

Just add another check to your if statement before your equals. e.g.

```
!(v.ValA == null && v.ValB == null)
```